# How to simplify a date rule

Tags: python, date

I have a date rule that handles dates between certain dates with different outcomes. I was wondering if there is a way to simplify/combine the rules?

```
date = "YYYY-MM-DD"
rule1_1993_start = "1993-02-01" #sets date to "2000-01-01"
rule1_1993_end = "1993-05-31"
rule1_1994_start = "1994-02-01"
rule1_1994_end = "1994-05-31"
rule2_1993_start = "1993-06-01" #keeps the same date
rule2_1993_end = "1993-12-01"
rule2_1994_start = "1994-06-01"
rule2_1994_end = "1994-12-01"
rule3_1993_start = "1993-01-01" #sets date to "1995-MM-DD"
rule3_1993_end = "1993-01-31"
rule3_1994_start = "1994-01-01"
rule3_1994_end = "1994-01-31"

if rule1_1993_start <= date <= rule1_1993_end: #date="1993-03-04"
      date = "2000-01-01"
if rule2_1993_start <= date <= rule1_1993_end: #date="1993-07-01"
      date = "1993-07-01"
if rule3_1993_start <= date <= rule1_1993_end: #date="1993-01-12"
      date = "1995-01-12"
```

Comment: I would turn each of these into a 3-tuple: The start date for the rule, the end date for the rule, and the resulting date that the rule returns.  Then you can simply loop over all of the rules and apply the one that matches.

Comment: Your "rules" seem to be incomplete. What would you do with, for example, '1994-01-01'?

Comment: Yes indeed this is rule3, I didn't want to overcrowd, but I edited it in now.

Comment: Of course you only need to test for date ranges that might need to be modified. There's no point in testing ranges when there's nothing to be done. Take a look at the excellent suggestion from @0x5453 and use 3-tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing dates can be a little tricky; there tend to be lots of corner cases. If you need a more production-quality function, I recommend you use Python's `time` module:

```
import time
def convert_date(date):                                                         
    return time.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

When your dates are in this format, you can use math operators (<, <=, etc) to do comparisons. You can also compare based on month and year, so for example your third rule becomes something like:

```
# If date in January 1993 or 1994
if((date.tm_year == 1993 || date.tm_year == 1994) && date.tm_mon == 1):
  ...
```

You can convert dates back to strings using Python's `strftime` routine:

```
def date_to_string(date):
  return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)
```

`strptime` docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

`strftime` docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime